# Use NS_REFINED_FOR_SWIFT without including Swift Runtime

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, xcode, runtime

I'm working on adding Swift annotations such as `NS_SWIFT_NAME` to my existing Objective-C project (distributed via. Cocoapods, Carthage, etc.), so that I can improve Swift interoperability without forcing ObjC users to add the Swift runtime.

```
@interface TestObject : NSObject

- (void)getFirstName:(NSString **)firstName;

@end
```

Which outputs really ugly Swift types:

```
func getFirstName(firstName: AutoreleasingUnsafeMutablePointer<NSString?>)
```

I want to work with the [`NS_REFINED_FOR_SWIFT`](https://briancoyner.github.io/2018/02/10/ns-refined-for-swift.html) annotation:

```
@interface TestObject : NSObject

- (void)getFirstName:(NSString **)firstName NS_REFINED_FOR_SWIFT;

@end
```

Adding Swift extensions for more Swifty method names:

```
public extension TestObject {
    func getFirstName() -> String? {
        var firstName: NSString? = nil
        __getFirstName(&firstName)
        return firstName as String?
    }
}
```

Is there a way to include this extension for those developers that have Swift code, but exclude it from Objective-C only codebases? I don't want to add the Swift runtime unnecessarily.

**EDIT:** Updated with better code example. [Source](https://academy.realm.io/posts/altconf-nikita-lutsenko-objc-swift-interoperability/)

Comment: Why don't you use `NS_SWIFT_NAME` instead of `NS_REFINED_FOR_SWIFT`?

Comment: @MartinR - I've updated with a better code example for `NS_REFINED_FOR_SWIFT`

Comment: (Not answering your question:) Write a nicer Objective-C method `-(NSString *)firstName` (possibly as a wrapper around the old method), and make the old one NS_SWIFT_UNAVAILABLE.

Comment: @MartinR - Not a bad idea. Thanks